# Dockerized laravel server denies POST requests

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Here is a *completely reproducible* docker image of a REST API Laravel server:

```dockerfile
FROM php
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install zip -y
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN composer create-project laravel/laravel frontend
WORKDIR frontend
COPY web.php web.php
RUN mv web.php routes
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "php", "artisan", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

The only thing I edited was a single endpoint (`web.php`):

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return csrf_token();
});

Route::post('/', function (Request $request) {
    if ($request->hasFile('source'    )) { return ">> GOOD ! <<"; }
    if ($request->hasFile('input.json')) { return ">> GOOD ! <<"; }

    $x = count($_FILES);

    return "DD >> $x << DD";
});
```

I build and run the docker image as follows:

```
$ docker build --tag host.translator.php --file Dockerfile .
$ docker run -p 8008:8000 -d -t --name translator.php host.translator.php
```

Then just like related posts say ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266593/3357352), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57940170/3357352), [and also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424808/3357352)):

```bash
$ Set-Variable -Name X -Value (curl.exe -X GET -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/)
# X holds the token:
# echo $X
# U263lUv3dz9PH7ySm3GmgUUjHjjWm78cqofODUmh
```

But when I try to use that token it doesn't work:

```
$ curl.exe --header "X-CSRFToken:$X" -X POST -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/ | Select-String "<title>Page Expired"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6851    0  6609  100   242  80486   2947 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 83548

        <title>Page Expired</title>
```

Any help is *very* much appreciated - thanks !

**EDIT**:

```bash
#
# used a new variable Z - just to be sure ...
#
$ Set-Variable -Name Z -Value (curl.exe -b cookiejar -X GET -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   282    0    40  100   242    527   3194 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3760
$ echo $Z # this looks good, right ?
aHvU5WOaGs9qxOIzgdYb90TJUKPDgDaNhYjQNALW
#
$ type .\cookiejar # this looks ... hmmm ... good (I think ?)
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_127.0.0.1     FALSE   /       FALSE   1711103819      laravel_session eyJpdiI6IllsOW9KdlVzT1ZPcUJDOUdQRnUyZHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiekpING13WFRaaDRLUHBUcVpNM0VjblBwVjlXM1VrSU1uYUF3dk43d0J6c0RvSDJ5UWZOU3lla1lKVjBNRnNVTXJOaTNMdmt3dlIvdW5HZDk1ODZUb0gxVWMySHh5cXBWeG5XbjVMQlpMQ2xoMzM0ODROQ1FGQ0NMQzFNaHNQMXMiLCJtYWMiOiI0MTg3ZTM0NTlmNWMzZGUyZDY3YzI2YWViYzc2MDZhMjAyMjA2NzE5YmRmYTRmYWRmYzQxODIzYmVlOThlZTkxIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D
#
# Now let's cross our fingers extra strong !
#
$ curl.exe -c cookiejar --header "X-CSRFToken:$Z" -X POST -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/ | Select-String "<title>Pa
ge Expired"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6851    0  6609  100   242  85705   3138 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 87833
242  83137   3044 --:--:-        <title>Page Expired</title>- --
:--:-- --:--:-- 85637
```

Comment: For it to be *completely reproducible*, I think we need the contents of your `input.json` file too :)

Comment: if you're using csrf tokens you also need to use a [cookie jar](https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html) and save and resend cookies because the csrf token is associated with the user session which is communicated using cookies

Comment: @apokryfos, I thought the only relevant info in the cookie was the token, no ?

Comment: @HansKilian here it is :) `{"name": "oren", "age": 6}`

Comment: The CSRF token is stored in the user's session and then verified by what is received from the client so the server needs to verify that the token actually belongs to the user who made the request (and the user is determined using the session)

Comment: @apokryfos you mean I should somehow add more info to the POST request ? or am I doing it completely wrong ?

Comment: Try sending the get request like `curl.exe -b cookiejar -X GET -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/ ` and the post request like `curl.exe -c cookiejar --header "X-CSRFToken:$X" -X POST -F "source=@input.json" http://127.0.0.1:8008/` to save and then send the cookies

Comment: @apokryfos, I edited the question to show your suggestion - it still doesn't work

Comment: @apokryfos Shouldn't the `-b` and `-c` options be switched? According to the man page,  `-c` stores cookies and `-b` sends them.

Comment: Have you tried doing post request in postman then check the curl code there?

Comment: @HansKilian, I tried it with the `-b`, `-c` flags switched but it still doesn't work. I don't use postman - but will install it if it can help (?)

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I installed postman, and sent a `GET` request (successfully) and a `POST` request that returned `Page Expired` like before ... any configuration I should do in postman ?

Comment: hmm... AFAIK, Page expire is error 419 missing csrf token. Try to follow this on how to add token in postman. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49249850/13933721

Comment: just do simple post request first without extra params and simple return json response to make sure that your post request is successful. then check postman's to curl function and try it to your bash.. if successful, then do your thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) is a way to protect the server from forgery.

See https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/csrf

In order to pass this validation in the normal way, you need to pass a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header (**not** `X-CSRFToken` as you did it with a typo) and pass a proper CSRF token.

The mechanism for CSRF token is as follows:

- the site allows you to run some entry points (some GET requests, for example) without passing CSRF
- and afterwards, you need to set the header for CSRF tokens properly upon any POST requests that you might send
- whenever a page/request is handled, the old CSRF token is invalidated and your session will get a new CSRF token which needs to be passed in the next POST instead of the previous one

So, if you are sending a POST request via CURL, then a CSRF token needs to be determined, true, but you will need to send the newest one.

You can exclude URLs from CSRF protection, **but be careful, don't reduce your security standards if possible** via

```
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ]);
})
```

and then the request will be handled properly. If it's an entry point (like in posting a JWT for SSO), then it makes sense to allow that specific end point to run without CSRF, for it is authenticating the user anyway. Otherwise, you will always need to obtain the latest CSRF token and add it to the header of your requests.

Comment: It works !! Thanks for the detailed answer ! I guess the last thing I didn't fully get is how the content of the `cookiejar` file relates to the last csrf token - they both change very request, but they are *not* the same hash (right ?) the cookiejar hash seems to be much longer

Comment: @OrenIshShalom happy to help. I suppose they are not the same hash, but I did not verify it.